# ASP.NET MVC 3 How to validate dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to validate Date field of a birthday selection section. I have a dropdownlist with 1-31 days listed down and the default value is "0" and the text is "Day". Code is below:

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItems> Date = new List<SelectListItems>
    {
        new SelectListItems{Value = "0", Text = "Day", Default = true},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "1", Text = "1"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "2", Text = "2"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "3", Text = "3"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "4", Text = "4"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "5", Text = "5"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "6", Text = "6"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "7", Text = "7"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "8", Text = "8"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "9", Text = "9"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "10", Text = "10"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "11", Text = "11"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "12", Text = "12"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "13", Text = "13"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "14", Text = "14"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "15", Text = "15"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "16", Text = "16"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "17", Text = "17"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "18", Text = "18"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "19", Text = "19"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "20", Text = "20"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "21", Text = "21"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "22", Text = "22"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "23", Text = "23"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "24", Text = "24"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "25", Text = "25"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "26", Text = "26"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "27", Text = "27"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "28", Text = "28"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "29", Text = "29"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "30", Text = "30"},
        new SelectListItems{Value = "31", Text = "31"}

    };
```

My model is as below:

```
 public class PaxInfoViewModel
{
    public bool IsChild
    {
        get { return Age != null; }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select the born Month")]
    public int BirthYear1 { get; set; }
    [Range(2, 12, ErrorMessage="Please select the born Month")]
    public int BirthMonth { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the born Date")]
    [Range(2, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please select the born Date")]
    public int BirthDate { get; set; }

}
```

My View is as below:

```
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="editor-label control-label">@Html.Label("Child " + i + " Birthday ")</div>
                    <div class="span1">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Rooms[roomCount - 1].Children[i - 1].BirthDate, new SelectList(Model.DropDown.Date, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "mini" })</div>
                    <div class="span2">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Rooms[roomCount - 1].Children[i - 1].BirthMonth, new SelectList(Model.DropDown.Month, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "small" })</div>
                     <div class="errorformat">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Rooms[roomCount - 1].Children[i - 1].BirthMonth)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Rooms[roomCount - 1].Children[i - 1].BirthDate)
                 </div></div>
```

This Date is need to validate. User must select a value other than the Default value.  How can I do that.Please help.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. ASP.NET MVC 3 Unobtrusive validation only validate "input" elements.

Therefore I had to do some changes to the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` code.

**Here what i did:**

On the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file, around code line 173(in my file) you can find this code line : `$(selector).find(":input[data-val=true]").each(function ()`, change it to: `$(selector).find("[data-val=true]").each(function ()`.

Also around line 289 you can find this code line : `element = $(options.form).find(":input[name=" + fullOtherName + "]")[0]`, change it to : `element = $(options.form).find("[name=" + fullOtherName + "]")[0]`

And in my View file I add the validation attributes to the dropdownlist as below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Yourmodelvariable, Yourlistitems, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "data-val-range-min", "1" }, { "data-val-range-max", "31" }, { "data-val-range", "Please select the born Date" }, { "data-val", "true" }, { "class", "mini" } }) "

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Yourmodelvariable)
```

You can add the validation attribute as you want to validate(In my case I want to validate a range), and it works for me as smooth as loose motion!.